# Ширина блока по наибольшему

Tags: html, css

возникла проблема с выравниванием ширины блока по наибольшему в колонке. Вот как это выглядит на данный момент: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы и нижний блок был шириной с верхний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый просто пример - обернуть эти элементы `div`ом и задать им (этим элементам) `width: 100%` - тогда они будут шириной с родителя.

```css
.width {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.elem {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="width">
  <div class="elem">asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</div>
  <div class="elem">asdasdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

---

Дополнил

```css
.width {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.elem {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="width">
  <button class="elem">asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</button>
  <button class="elem">asdasdasdasd</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Я пытался так сделать, но у меня не получилось, потому что ширина кнопки зависит от ширины тега <button>, а ему предшествуют другие теги.
Вот мой код: https://imgur.com/a/GLrom6u

Comment: @Daniil Lobchenko смотри мой ответ, он рабочий. П.с. у меня просьба, зайди в мой профиль и плюсани мои отрицательные вопросы. Мне система не позволяет задавать вопросы свои.

Comment: @DaniilLobchenko, дополнил ответ кодом, где используется `<button>` вместо `<div>` и всё работает.

Comment: @DaniilLobchenko, ошибся, для родителя нужен `display: inline-block`

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 хороший вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.block {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: yellow;
    color: #222;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
Пример 1:<br><br>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="block">Привет Мир, Я Супер!</div>
  <div class="block">Привет!</div>
</div>
<br><br>
Пример 2 (с добавленным третьим блоком)<br><br>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="block">Привет Мир, Я Супер!</div>
  <div class="block">Привет!</div>
  <div class="block">Я Супер человек! Супер человек!</div>
</div>
```